# How to set value to global variable in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a form

```
  <form method="get" id="searchform" >
    <input value="Search..." id="s" type="text">
  </form>
```

and a jquery code

```
<script language="javascript">
    var searchformValue;
    $('#searchform').submit(function(){
        searchformValue = $('#s').val();
        return searchformValue;
        });

</script>
```

but when i alert the search formvalue outside the function

```
<script language="javascript">
    var searchformValue;
    $('#searchform').submit(function(){
        searchformValue = $('#s').val();
        return searchformValue;
        });
            alert(searchformValue);

</script>
```

it returns unidentified.Why??

Any solutions for it?

Edit: I want to have the searchformValue with the submit value after the function runs

Comment: you could initialise it's value, in which case wont be undefined any more.

Answer (score 4):

When you -

```
alert(searchformValue);
```

The submit function will not have been called (as it won't get called until the form on your page is submitted), so the value of `searchformValue` will still be undefined.

Comment: The value will be set in the method, but only when the method is called. I'm not sure what it is you're trying to achieve - what do you want to appear in the alert box? Do you want the alert box to appear when the page loads or when the form is is submitted?

Comment: I'm guessing by the names given to the variables. Do you simply want to **edit** the value submitted by the form?

Comment: @ipr101 i'm trying to insert the searchformValue to twitter plugin.So that twitter plugin will popup according to the searchformVlaue.Got it?????

Answer (score 1):

You are calling alert() before the code runs. You need to call it at the end of the handler or afterwards so that there is actually a value to display.

You don't need a global variable here, but simply drop the 'var' to make it one. FYI, global variables are evil.

Comment: A global variable turned me into a newt!

Comment: That's trange, the normal side effect is warts and occasional rips in the space-time continuum...

Comment: You prefer life as a newt? Understandable, although perhaps I'm misunderstanding your ambigious phrase...

Answer (score 0):

When working with events, you must realise the event has to to take place for the event's callback to work.

Therefore, the code you have will initialise `searchformValue`, attach a callback to the `submit` event of the form, and then `alert(searchformValue)` whilst the variable is `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
 var searchformValue;
```

to

```
 var searchformValue = ""
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it right, but the variable is not being given a value until the submit handler is called. This is what you want, I suspect.

Answer (score 0):

This will behave as expected:

```
var searchformValue;
$('#searchform').submit(function(){
    searchformValue = $('#s').val();
    alert(searchformValue);

    return searchformValue;
});
alert("This will alert immediately");
```

`.submit()` is not blocking. It doesn't wait for the form to submit before moving on to the next statement. Anything you want to happen after submitting needs to go in the callback function.

Comment: i'm trying to insert the searchformValue to twitter plugin.So that twitter plugin will popup according to the searchformVlaue.